# lightbend config : pass dynamic values in application.properties file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, config, typesafe-config

I am using [lightbend](https://github.com/lightbend/config) in my scala code so that my `application.properties` file is away from my jar. I need to pass the current date in `application.properties` file.

```
Date_read_write = 20190828
```

how do I make this to pick up dynamically, if it is shell script I can mention

```
Date_read_write=`date +%Y%m%d`
```

how do I do a similar step in `application.properties` file?

**Update for time addition**

below is my `application.properties` file:

```
hdfs_link = hdfs://XX.XXX.XXX.XX:8080/sessions/data/events
mediaKey = 1234
eventName = media
Date_read_write = 20190815
time = *_W
parts = *
```

i am using above to generate `hdfs://XX.XXX.XXX.XX:8080/sessions/data/events/1234/media/20190815/*_W/*`

using :

```
val conf = ConfigFactory.load() 
val hdfs_path = conf.getString("hdfs_link")+"/"+conf.getString("mediaKey")+"/"+conf.getString("eventName")+"/"+conf.getString("Date_read_write")+"/"+conf.getString("time")+"/"+conf.getString("parts")
```

but when i add

```
--driver-java-options -DDate_read_write=`date --date='1 days ago' '+%Y%m%d'`
```

to my spark submit commad, my URL is turing to `hdfs://XX.XXX.XXX.XX:8080/sessions/data/events/1234/media/20190828/*/*`

i have no clue why this addition changes the value of `time`.

Below is my spark submit command:

> nohup spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --num-executors
>   20 --executor-cores 6 --driver-memory 10g --executor-memory 10g
>   --class metrics.MasterAggregateTable --files application.properties --driver-java-options -Dconfig.file=application.properties --driver-java-options -DDate_read_write=`date +%Y%m%d` --jars com.datastax.spark_spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.3.0.jar
>   UserMetrics.jar &

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [override all the settings](https://github.com/lightbend/config#optional-system-or-env-variable-overrides) in `application.properties` by system properties.

```
java -DDate_read_write=`date +%Y%m%d` -jar yourapp.jar
```

> In default uses of the library, exact-match system properties already override the corresponding config properties.

This does not require any changes to the configuration file inside of the jar.

Comment: This works, but i have other issue because of this, it is making my next parameter as `*` instead of taking the one from config file. 
i am generating a hdfs url from config file so my next parameter is `time` so before using above code it used to be `20190829/00` and now it became `20190829/*` any idea why this is happening? all i added to spark submit command is `--driver-java-options -DDate_read_write=\`date +%Y%m%d\``

Comment: @toofrellik Please update your question to include how you define `time` .

Comment: Can you also show the code that reads the configuration to produce the URL?

Comment: i am tired of using all sorts of options, even tried with creating a bash variable and sending that to the spark submit command but still when the job runs it is making `time` as `*` no idea why!

Comment: It is probably something else/silly. Do you redefine `time` somewhere? Try changing the name to something longer such as `Time_read_write`. Also try putting the `*_W` in doublequotes.

Comment: You should also be able to do the concatenation in the config file instead of in code: `target_hdfs_path = ${hdfs_link}/${mediaKey}/${eventName}`. That way you can also override the whole thing as a last resort.

Comment: Got it worked! its a silly miss, `-D<var name>` statement should be before `--files` command else it will pick from local `application.properties` file. that was the issue.

Answer (score 3):

You could consider using an environment variable for that. 
Just add environment variable substitution in your `application.properties` file:

```
date = ${DATE}
```

Then while you run your app just set `DATE` variable:

```
 DATE=`date +%Y%m%d` java -jar yourapp.ja
```